# Java : Parsing Date String using SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java

My date string is like this `dd.MM.yyyy-HH.mm.ss` .
I am doing following:

```
String s_date= "13.06.2012-12.12.12"
Date d_date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.YYYY-HH.mm.ss", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(s_date);
```

But it is throwing `Unparseable date: "13.06.2012-12.12.12"` Exception.

How can I make it work for the given date-time format ?

Comment: That actually doesn't throw an exception for me - which surprises me, given that you haven't provided any time parts in your format string...

Comment: it works fine for me.. no exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using capital `Y`.

Try:

```
Date d_date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy-HH.mm.ss", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(s_date);
```

[Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 2):

You should add time as well:

```
 new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.YYYY-HH.mm.ss", Locale.ENGLISH)
```

Comment: That was a typo .. now I edited but still its throwing the same exception. I am doing this:
`Date d_date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.YYYY-HH.mm.ss", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(s_date); `

Answer (score 1):

`String s_date= "13.06.2012-12.12.12"` doesn't fit your pattern `dd.MM.YYYY`. You should remove the part after the `-` if you want date without hours:

```
s_date = s_date.substring(0, s_date.indexOf('-'));
```

or change your pattern as Michał said.

Comment: Using what you suggested eliminates the exception, but the date object d_date gets a date which is not right.. ie for any date string it gives this : `Sun Dec 30 00:00:00 IST 2012`.

Answer (score 0):

do like this.

```
String d=new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy").format(date);
System.out.println(d);
```

Comment: I dont want to just print it, rather change it into Date type. 
So this error comes when I do what you suggested `Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to Date`

Comment: boss its like you want spoon feeding.:)

Comment: No, you just didn't got the question.. format gives the string from date object, not vice-versa. :) I was encountering an issue while trying something, its not called spoon feeding. :)

Answer (score 0):

String s_date= ""13.06.2012-12.12.12";

this is wrong

use String s_date= "13.06.2012-12.12.12";

Comment: that was a typo.. Edited it. Thanks.