# Parsing a Date from a String in Java?

Tags: java, date

I'm trying to parse a String to a Date Object, as part of a loading functionality for my program, as seen below:

```
    String dateString = "Wed Jan 18 23:22:18 EST 2017";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss zzz YYYY");
    try {
        Date scheduleItemDate = sdf.parse(dateString);
        System.out.println(scheduleItemDate.toString());
    }
    catch (ParseException e) {
        System.out.println("Exception");
    }
```

Although the date should be the same as in dateString above, the program prints out the following date:

```
    Wed Jan 04 23:22:18 EST 2017
```

The above date is basically two full weeks behind the original date, I'm not sure as to how I am getting this, anything I am doing wrong?

Comment: The hour should be `HH`, not `hh` - *"h Hour in am/pm (1-12)"*

Comment: And year should be `yyyy` not `YYYY` - *"Y Week year"*

Comment: the y thing fixes it.

Comment: Yeah, you guys were right, thanks so much!

Comment: What research did you do prior to asking? For example, it seems that [this question: Java : Parsing Date String using SimpleDateFormat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17086261/java-parsing-date-string-using-simpledateformat) could have helped you.

Answer (score 7):

The hour should be `HH`, not `hh`

> h Hour in am/pm (1-12)

And year should be `yyyy` not `YYYY`

> Y Week year

ALWAYS consult the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) first

```
String dateString = "Wed Jan 18 23:22:18 EST 2017";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
try {
    Date scheduleItemDate = sdf.parse(dateString);
    System.out.println(dateString);
    System.out.println(scheduleItemDate.toString());
    System.out.println(sdf.format(scheduleItemDate));
} catch (ParseException e) {
    System.out.println("Exception");
}
```

Which now prints...

```
Wed Jan 18 23:22:18 EST 2017
Wed Jan 18 23:22:18 EST 2017
Wed Jan 18 23:22:18 EST 2017
```

Comment: Great explanation and reference link!

Comment: And for something like this, a good place to start is the examples in the javadoc page because reading these definitions one by one will make you become a hermit.

Comment: Thanks for the javadoc link! :)

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**: the newer `DateTimeFormatter` and friends are somewhat more helpful in debugging issues like yours compared to the outdated `SimpleDateFormat`.

This is not the answer you were asking for, but it may be the answer you want. If there is any way you can (which there is), drop the outdated classes `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date` in favour of the modern ones in the `java.time` package. The way to do in your case isn’t much different from your code. PLEASE NOTE: I am deliberately including your error.

```
    String dateString = "Wed Jan 18 23:22:18 EST 2017";
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss zzz YYYY"); // wrong
    try {
        ZonedDateTime scheduleItemDate = ZonedDateTime.parse(dateString, dtf);
        System.out.println(scheduleItemDate.toString());
    }
    catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
        System.out.println("Exception");
    }
```

The output is different, though: the above snippet prints

```
Exception
```

I am serious when I say I consider this an improvement. There was a bug in your program all the time, and now the program tells you there is bug. On my computer, the exception message I get is

> Text 'Wed Jan 18 23:22:18 EST 2017' could not be parsed at index 0

Index 0, that’s where it says `Wed`. What’s wrong with that? The problem is my computer runs Danish locale. If you want to parse a date-time string in English on computers of different locales, you need to specify an English-speaking locale, for example:

```
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss zzz YYYY",
                                                        Locale.ENGLISH);
```

The same holds true if you are using `SimpleDateFormat`. With this correction I get a different exception message:

> Text 'Wed Jan 18 23:22:18 EST 2017' could not be parsed: Invalid value
>   for ClockHourOfAmPm (valid values 1 - 12): 23

Isn’t this message wonderfully precise? The format had expected a value between 1 and 12 (inclusive) where you put 23. As menitoned in the comments, this is because you were using lowercase `hh` where you intended uppercase `HH`. After fixing this, we get

> Text 'Wed Jan 18 23:22:18 EST 2017' could not be parsed: Unable to
>   obtain ZonedDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {DayOfMonth=18,
>   DayOfWeek=3, MonthOfYear=1,
>   WeekBasedYear[WeekFields[SUNDAY,1]]=2017},ISO,America/New_York
>   resolved to 23:22:18 of type java.time.format.Parsed

It’s more cryptic, but it does mention the problem that MadProgrammer also points out: the week-based year. This is what uppercase `YYYY` gives you (and it’s a very common mistake, judging from the many questions on Stack Overflow with this exact problem). Let’s fix that too:

```
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy",
                                                        Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Now we get the expected:

> 2017-01-18T23:22:18-05:00[America/New_York]

One final word of caution: the three and four letter time zone abbreviations like `EST` come with some negative surprises too. `DateTimeFormatter` understands `EST` as UTC-5, which I suppose is what you want with a date in January (winter). For a date in the summer, would you still be expecting UTC-5, or would you expect EDT, that is, UTC-4? In your case you may be able to solve the ambiguity by supplying `EDT` for Eastern Daylight Time, but generally it’s better to avoid those abbreviation and use the longer time zone IDs like `America/New_York` and/or offsets like `-05:00`.